# Ubuntu Apache2 server not allowing CORS or reading .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have a couple issues, the first is my apache2 server is not reading `.htaccess`

I have `apache2.conf` setup like so:

```
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I enabled mod_headers with `a2enmod headers`

In `.htaccess`, I have:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

When trying to access via a javascript file, I get:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I added:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Every time I edited `apache2.conf` I restarted apache2 with `service apache2 restart`

To `apache2.conf` and it instead gives me a `500 internal server error`. I can access the page with the browser, but through javascript, I cannot. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to turn on mod_rewrite (`a2enmod rewrite`) and the .php file had errors that I couldn't see, for which I used:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 include("file_with_errors.php");
?>
```

From the php manual site, on this page: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also, if you'd like to turn on error reporting all of the time (which I did), changing the following in `php.ini` as so:

```
display_errors = Off
```

-to-

```
display_errors = On
```

Is ideal.